# What is GitHub using for real-time updates? No more websocket or SSE?

Tags: github, websocket, real-time, server-sent-events

Until recently when I opened the developer tool on a GitHub page I could see an open listening websocket receiving the news for an issue page or a code change or something else real-time.

Today I can't find any websocket connection anymore or SSE calls.

What are they using now for real-time updates or events?

Comment: Could it be a browser change, i.e. simply not showing the information any more? You mentioned using Chrome - is the behaviour the same in Firefox?

Comment: Yeah. The same with Firefox! Can you try?

Comment: @FredHors I would assume writing to GitHub support at this point is your safest bet: https://support.github.com/request

Comment: @VonC, this is not an issue for me. I'm just curious. Is this a browser thing or a GitHub thing? Can you try it in your browser? Do you see something? What are they using for real-time events? Just curiosity...

Comment: I have observed the same change. I year ago a websocket was open to get notifications from the server, and this websocket disappeared. However, if I add a reaction on e.g. an issue (over another browser), then new requests are sent to the server (fetch calls) to update the view, and as initator of these calls the code updatable-content.ts:23 is listed, and these calls originate in a class called socket-channel.ts. I assume that the answer might be found in this file.

Comment: I also want to know the answer.  Its like magic to me now, that github update their webpage in realtime without any streaming protocols.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing mentioned about SSE or websocket on:

- [GitHub Engineering](https://githubengineering.com/)
- [GitHub blog](https://github.blog/) (and its [changelog](https://github.blog/changelog/))
- [GitHub public roadmap](https://github.com/github/roadmap)

So check first if the issue persists over the next few days, because WebSockets or [SSE (Server-sent events)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-sent_events) should not have silently "vanished" from GitHub pages (although there was a [recent incident](https://www.githubstatus.com/incidents/ls7h2sdydbhl)).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I get updates. Surprisingly everything works fine, but I don't see websockets or SSE calls in the dev tools! I'm using Chrome.

Comment: @FredHors Do you see the issue from Chrome on other computers? Did you upgrade Chrome recently?

Comment: There are no issues, @Von.

Comment: I just wanna see what's happening. Both Firefox and Chrome do not show me nor ws or sse.

Comment: Why? What are they using?

Comment: I don't see anything in the WS tab of the developer tool in my Chrome 85 either. Did you see them on GitHub Pages specifically? or any page of github.com?

Comment: Any page. I'm just curious about what tech are they using for real-time updates! It's amazing!

Comment: @FredHors And you saw those WS/SEE last week?

Comment: A few months ago

Comment: But why is nothing now visible anyway?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221773/discussion-between-vonc-and-fred-hors).